# Float: Block Formatting Context

Tags: html, css

```
    <nav>
       <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

    nav ul{
       margin: 0;
       padding-left: 50px;
       list-style: none;
    }

    nav ul li {
       float:left;
       border:1px solid #878E63;
       width: 15%;
    }
```

In the code above in the `nav ul li { ...}`, I set the float property to left. I am a little confused on how the bfc works in this case. I know that "in a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block (where the containing block in this case is the ul, correct?). Each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch)". But when I run the code it gives me this output:
[image]

The list elements are aligned horizontally in the block formatting context created by the float property, instead of vertically as it is supposed to? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Just remove the float:left; from the 'nav ul li' it will list your boxes vertically.

Comment: due to float left its display horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote is taken from a section headed [9.4 Normal flow](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#normal-flow). But floats are taken out of the flow and laid out by different rules. The block boxes that are still in the flow continue to be laid out in the vertical manner described, (and the floated elements are invisible to them)

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. So does that mean that since floats are taken out of the flow and laid out by different rules a block formatting context is not created when you use the float property?

Comment: A floated box itself forms a block formatting context for its contents. But it is outside normal flow with respect to its containing block formatting context.

Comment: Oh ok. So the normal flow in the containing block formatting context is vertical but the float:left will make the elements flow outside of this normal vertical flow in a bfc correct?

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected as you are putting `floadt:left` on `li` element in this case all the `li` element will move towards left and have the `width:15%;` which you have mentioned.

Comment: So does the float:left not create a Block Formatting Context? Since in a bfc the elements have to aligned vertically correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you've mistaken the section of the document you were reading. If you want to use floats you have to read this: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#floats

What you're getting is the expected behaviour. If you want to stack the items vertically then don't use floats.